# Parse pandas dataframe based on id number and sting value in adjacent column

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I am attempting to parse data based 1. id number and then 2. the first time a value appears through the end (in this example: 'David' would start the parse on the end of the parsing would exterminate with a new id number.

Comment: '''
 df= pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4],'name':['mark','david','sam','david','mark','sam','sam','david','chase']})
 df
'''
 
'''
final = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,2,4],'name':['david','sam','david','david','sam','david',]})
final
'''

Comment: for id==1 you pick {David,sam}.  what happened to mark?

Comment: he didnt make it

Comment: Could you extend the explanation of the logic behind the desired output, please?